# Left-align list items in a vertical side menu

Tags: css, menu

I am using the slideout jquery plugin (https://github.com/mango/slideout) to create a vertical side menu that's hidden until the menu button is clicked. I want each list item to take up the entire length of the green container, but when I set li item width to 100%, the li items get pushed out of the green area. Is there a way to align them to the left without manual setting a left margin? I've tried text-align:left, but that didn't work.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 256px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}
.slideout-panel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slideout-open,
.slideout-open body,
.slideout-open .slideout-panel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideout-open .slideout-menu {
  display: block;
}
#navigation {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  border-left: 10px solid #000;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  /*margin-left:-25px;*/
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>
      <input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="gn-search"><a href="#"><span class="icon icon-search">Search</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about"><span class="icon icon-lucky">I'm Feeling Lucky</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
<ul>
```

has a default padding-left value that you haven't set to 0. As a result, your

```
<li>
```

are getting pushed to the right. Furthermore, your 10px left border is adding another 10px of width, giving your

```
<li>
```

a width of 210px.

Try setting the width of the

```
<li>
```

to 190px and setting

```
padding-left: 0
```

on your

```
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `padding-left` of `#navigation` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding-left:0px to #navigation.

```
#navigation {
   padding-left: 0px;
 }
```